# median() coming back as NA for df of integers?

Tags: r

Have a data frame of numerical data and using apply with median along columns. I'm getting NA for the median even though there are some non-zero entries in the columns. I did str(df) to ensure all of the df is integer and it is. What does it mean when R says the median is NA? Thanks.

```
v1  v2  v3..... 
1   3   4
0   0   0
.   .   .
```

Also, I got a bunch warnings like this: 
           "1: In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half +  ... :
           argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  It is not clear how you got the error. Based on this example, it works `set.seed(24);df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 10*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)); apply(df1, 2, median)`

Answer (score 0):

My solution it is trivial but maybe there are some NAs you did not see. Try to use apply with the `na.rm = FALSE` in the last argument (the ellipsis).

Using the code provided by akrun.

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 10*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
apply(df1, 2, median)
```

I add some NA

```
df1[ 3 , "V2" ] <- NA
```

and then use sapply (which is the same due to the fact that a data frame is a type of list )

```
sapply(df1, median, c(na.rm = TRUE))
```

edit:

consider that `str(df1)` return int even if there is an NA at row 3 column V2.